# Making labels sort correctly in Gmail's Priority Inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, priority-inbox

I have a label called "Action Needed," in Gmail and I want to use Priority Inbox to create a section specifically for this "Action Needed" label. In the Inbox configuration screen, I have these settings:

[image: The Priority Inbox settings page, where the third inbox pane should be set to display the "Action Needed" label.]

Seems simple enough. Just set the third pane to display the "Action Needed" label and I should be good to go, right?

When I go back out to my mailbox, I find this fun little thing happening:

[image: The Inbox.]

Turns out that when I actually go check out the Inbox, there is *a* message hanging out in the proper location, but every other "Action Needed" message is still in the "Important" section. I don't particularly understand why this is happening.

- The message currently in the "Action Needed" section is itself marked important.
- Many of the messages in the "Important" section have only "Action Needed" as their label (not shown).

What could possibly be causing this to happen? Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug that is causing this issue?